# How can I see full order details for each time a certain coupon code was used in magento?

Tags: mysql, magento

We are trying to collect data on each person that used a certain coupon code "NEWCUSTOMER". We are trying to get the order details including their name, email address, and what they ordered.

Is the rule_id connected to an order in any way in the database? The magento databases don't seem to be all that friendly when you are trying to write your own mySQL statement to figure this information out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to your previous question which i have also answered for you: [Find the name and email address of non-members who used coupon code in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144725/find-the-name-and-email-address-of-non-members-who-used-coupon-code-in-magento)

The coupon code used on an order is actually a property of the order: `coupon_code`

It sounds from your question that you are directly querying the db, if so then you are looking for the `coupon_code` field in the `sales_flat_order` table.

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_email` FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE  `coupon_code` = 'your_awesome_coupon_code' AND `customer_group_id` = 0
```

Or, via magento...

```
 $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_firstname')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_lastname')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('coupon_code')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_group_id', Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('coupon_code', 'NEWCUSTOMER');
```

Comment: I did double up, didn't I? Sorry about that! Appreciate you taking the time to answer twice! --- I would love to do it through Magento, but I don't even know where to start. Does anyone have a link to help me incorporate it straight into the Magento code?